# UILabel inside scroll view autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I have following views' hierarchy:

[image]

With the following layout:

[image]

My goal is to make green and red label with variable heights with following constraints:

- Each label takes all height it requires
- Bottom padding to yellow view is calculated on bigger label
- Smaller label doesn't stretch to bigger label's height

If I specify bottom spacing constraint as `equal` smaller label takes the same space as smaller one and its content is vertically centered (and I don't want this). If I specify bottom constraint as `equal or greater` scroll view has ambiguous height. Any ideas?

Comment: Add one more `View` around those labels. Play around with constraints and you'll figure it out.

Comment: @mostruash can you provide an example please? I have no idea how to make constraints even with additional views

Comment: you say you have no idea how to make constraints... how did you create the view hierarchy and constraints in your example?